# Does Close method in Statement abort the request of DB also in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I wanted to know, does calling close method in Statement class also aborts the sql query in database, similar to how cancel method do?

By aborting a sql query, I mean sending something like HTTP DELETE request to the server to cancel a query.

Does something like this should also be done by close() method if in case application does not call cancel() method.

Comment: What do you mean with "abort"?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I have edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Close method in Statement class it is used to free up the resources used, this is because Connections to Derby are resources external to an application, and the garbage collector will not close them automatically. Note that a close method causes Derby to abort an in-flight transaction but a does NOT roll back the transaction.

You can see a detailed explanation in https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/devguide/cdevconcepts839085.html

Comment: But does it _commit_ the transaction?

Comment: A statement close shouldn't abort or rollback a transaction. In auto-commit it should commit, and when auto-commit is disabled, a statement close should definitely not rollback a transaction.

Comment: Yes it should commit the transaction cause close method does not roll back the transaction.

Comment: A statement close should only commit a transaction if the connection is in auto-commit and the statement was not yet finished (as in: a result set was still open).

Comment: If close method does not rollback a transaction, so does that means that cancel statement also does not rollbacks the transaction?

Comment: Cancel method cancels the Statement object if both the DBMS and driver support aborting an SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

Closing a statement closes the statement handle and should end and de-allocate any statement resources held by the database systems for that specific statement handle.

I'm not sure what you mean with 'abort', but if you attempt to close a statement while a method call of  `execute`, `executeQuery` or `executeUpdate` is currently running, the behaviour is driver-dependent, but likely it will wait until that method call completes before it closes the statement. If you want to abort an in-progress statement execution, you should use `Statement.cancel()`.

If you attempt to close a statement while a result set is still open (that is `executeQuery` finished, but you haven't read or explicitly closed the result set), the result set will be closed, and any server-resources associated with that result set (e.g. a server-side cursor) will be closed as well. However, similar to an execute, if a fetch is in-progress (e.g. as part of a `ResultSet.next()` call), the close may wait until that fetch is complete, and use of `Statement.cancel()` may be necessary to abort such a fetch.

Comment: If I close the Statement object while the result set was still fetching the output from the server/database and also does not call the cancel method from Statement class, then it will close the resultset object but will it cancel the already running query in the server/database by calling something like HTTP DELETE?

Comment: @Paras That depends on the driver, and whether or not it fetches the complete result set during `executeQuery`, or if it fetches rows on demand while calling `resultSet.next()`. But generally, I would assume that if a driver fetches during `executeQuery`, then a call to `close()` will likely block (wait) until that is complete due to locking or other thread-safety measures, or otherwise cancel the fetch in progress before closing.